# TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable error when using seaborn pairplot ?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning

i'm new to python and machine learning and try to learn the subject , i'm following an online course ,
i have imported a dataset in jupyter notebook  and try to execute following python script on it

```
#creating a scatter plot matrix
%matplotlib inline

import seaborn as sns
num_cols = ["Age","Height","Weight","Duration","Heart_Rate","Body_Temp","Calories"]
sns.pairplot(frame(num_cols),size=2)
```

my dataset as follows

[image]

but when i run the code i get

> TypeError     Traceback (most recent call last)
>     in ()
>         4 import seaborn as sns
>         5 num_cols = ["Age","Height","Weight","Duration","Heart_Rate","Body_Temp","Calories"]
>   ----> 6 sns.pairplot(frame(num_cols),size=2)
>
> TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable

As a begginer i can't find a solution for this if anyone can help on this 
 very much appreciated.

thanks.

Comment: When you do : `frame(num_cols)`, you are calling (invoking the `__call__` method of) `frame`. The `DataFrame` object is not callable, so you can't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found the issue , and thought this will help for a beginner i have missed square brackets in

```
sns.pairplot(frame(num_cols),size=2)
```

it should be

```
sns.pairplot(frame[num_cols],size=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create an intermediate DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

%matplotlib inline

import seaborn as sns
num_cols = ["Age","Height","Weight","Duration","Heart_Rate","Body_Temp","Calories"]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=num_cols)
sns.pairplot(df,size=2)
```